# What does the phrase "out in the field" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> It enables a large global equipment manufacturer to send translated operations manuals to their technicians **out in the field**.

What does "*out in the field*" mean?

Comment: It could mean something like: "not-at-headquarters" or "away-from-the-office" or "with-the-client-base". The 'field' could be 'the-field-of-operations", where the operations actually take place.

Comment: *In the field* means where the manufacturer's equipment is installed and in use, i.e. on their customers' premises.

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary search clears this up:

> In conditions that you find in the real world, not in a laboratory or classroom
>   *The new drugs have not yet been tested in the field.*

([MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in-the-field))

As such, you example *their technicians out in the field* is referring to technicians who are not in the laboratory but out in the real world.

Do be aware that it does not necessarily mean that they are in a physical field.

It originates from the army being out *in the field* (usually literally) which then came to mean in any sort of real world situation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by analogy with a farm where "out in the field" (i.e. "not in the barn or house") would mean "at work plowing, seeding, harvesting, etc." or "performing relevant farming tasks", it means "away from the central office", "at the location of a job to be done", or even "performing practical tasks as opposed to the administrative ones usually handled in a central office".

Answer (score 0):

It means out of the office at various locations that can change from one day to the next.  Since technicians out in the field usually will be at the site of a customer or en route to and from various locations there is no way to pinpoint where they all are at a point in time.  This expression serves the purpose of letting one know that the technicians are working in different places other than here.